# Non-invocable member 'ListBox.Items" cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, items

So this code should e correct since it was converted from VB to C# and it gives me this error.

```
         private void lstItems_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // validate item is selected
        int itemIndex = lstItems.SelectedIndex;

        // get price of selected item and add to order list
        lstOrder.Items.Add(lstItems.Items(itemIndex).ToString());
        decimal ThisPrice = listItemPrices[itemIndex];
        listOrderPrices.Add(ThisPrice);
        recalculateTotals();

        // get string value of selected item and add to order listbox


        // display totals from calculation performing functions
       }
```

My error is on the lstOrder.Items.Add(lstItems.Items(itemIndex).ToString(();
How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: `lstItems.Items(itemIndex)` You used `(` when you meant to use `[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Basic is fairly unique in using parentheses for array indexing. When you converted to C#, you forgot to switch this to the standard square brackets. `lstItems.Items(itemIndex)` should be `lstItems.Items[itemIndex]`.

Comment: I tried that before and it still kept erroring on me.  Thank you.